# Screen tearing apart when switching from Intel to Nvidia

Tags: 18.04, intel, nvidia-optimus, xps

I have an XPS-15 with Intel & Nvidia cards.  When I switched to Nvidia from Intel, this is what my screen is like:https://m.imgur.com/a/VPIgvt1

This is my first time ever owning a machine with Nvidia.

Comment: Type in screen tearing in the search bar on this site and get many possible workarounds.

Comment: @ubfan1 I've tried most of them